# What are two disjoint stationary subsets of ω1?

Tags: set-theory

I know if cf(μ)≥ ω2 then two disjoint stationary subsets of μ are {α less than μ : cf(α)=ω} and {α less than μ : cf(α)=ω1}. But I'm not sure what two disjoint stationary sets of ω1 are. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A standard construction is via Ulam matrices. It achieves more, allowing you to split any stationary subset of $\omega_1$ into $\omega_1$ many disjoint stationary sets (and the argument applies to any successor cardinal). To define such a matrix, one needs for instance a family $(f_\alpha\mid \alpha<\omega_1)$ where each $f_\alpha$ is an injection from $\alpha$ into $\omega$. No such family can be "explicitly exhibited" in the sense that there are models where choice fails and no such family exists.

Comment: (Note that for each (non-zero) $\alpha<\omega_1$ there are many injections $f:\alpha\to\omega$. The issue is that it is not possible to select "simultaneously" one such function for each countable $\alpha$, without appealing to the axiom of choice.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no concrete example. They can be constructed using the axiom of choice. The relevant theorem is that any stationary subset of $\omega_1$ is the union of $\omega_1$ many disjoint stationary subsets. A nice exposition can be found in Jech.

Comment: Are you sure? I think there are concrete examples. The question says "Find two disjoint stationary subsets of ω1." I've also seen a lemma (without proof) that there are two disjoint stationary subsets of ω1. I've had a look at the theorem in Jech but it hasn't helped me with this question

Comment: where did this question come from ?

Comment: @user2034: It's consistent with $\mathbf{ZF}$ that every stationary subset of $\omega_1$ contains a club set (and, necessarily, $\mathbf{AC}$ fails); in such a model $\omega_1$ cannot have disjoint stationary sets. You could give an explicit example in $\omega_2$, however.

Comment: @user2034: I wrote a fairly comprehensive answer about the need for the axiom of choice (although from the point of view of large cardinals) for the assumption that there are two disjoint stationary sets http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008420/consistency-strength-of-the-club-ultrafilter/

Comment: (@user2034 Note that the explicit example of disjoint stationary subsets of $\omega_2$ also uses choice, since it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ have countable cofinality.)

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I've found the lemma with proof [here](http://imgur.com/T7ouLV4). So if we assume choice this is valid?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above AC is required to find two disjoint stationary in $\omega_{1}$ but the more concrete (which is of course not concrete, but worth mentioned) example I have seen is the following (due to Banach):

Consider an injection $f:\omega_{1}\to\Bbb R$ and for each $q\in\Bbb Q$ the sets $A_{q}=\{\alpha<\omega_{1}; f(\alpha)<q\}$
and $B_{q}=\{\alpha<\omega_{1}; f(\alpha)>q\}$. It is immediate
that for every $q\in\Bbb Q$, $A_{q},B_{q}$ are disjoint, thus
our goal is to find some $q\in\Bbb Q$ such that
$A_{q},B_{q}$ are stationary.

This can be done as follows: consider the sets

$$I=\{q\colon A_{q} \
\text{contains a cub set}\}, \ \ \ J=\{q\colon B_{q} \
\text{contains a cub set}\}. $$

Observe then that $\sup J\leq \inf I$ and that the set

$$C:=\left(\cap_{q\in J}B_{q}\right)\bigcap
        \left(\cap_{p\in I}A_{p}\right)$$

contains a cub set (as by definition of $I$ and $J$ it
contains a countable intersection of cub sets) and
that each element of $C$ lies in the
interval $\left[\sup J,\inf I\right]$. Since now a cub set
is uncountable it follows that $\sup J<\inf I$ and so we
can find $q\in\Bbb Q$ such that $q\not\in I\cup J$. It then
can be 'easily' seen
that $A_{q},B_{q}$ are stationary, which ends the proof.

Comment: Very nice. We do need countable choice to know that a cub is uncountable (i.e. that $cf(\omega_1)\ne \omega$) and that the intersection of a non-empty countable family of cubs is cub.