# Are there special or interesting non-principal ultrafilters?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, set-theory, filters

While non-principal ultrafilters cannot be explicitly constructed that doesn't mean that one cannot uniquely specify one of them under the assumption of their existence.

> Is there an example of a uniquely determined non-principal ultrafilter? Say on $\Bbb N$.

If thats not possible is it common to separate non-principal ultrafilters into different types? Or are they most often treated as an unreachable homogenous blob which provides theorems?

Comment: Not already mentioned in the existing answers and maybe more topological in flavour there are also P-points, Q-points,  and Ramsey ultrafilters. For the latter in particular there is a somewhat explicit construction under CH. Ramsey ultrafilters are the minimal elements in the Rudin-Keisler order and more generally being RK-inequivalent is a way to tell ultrafilters apart.

Comment: Looking at $\beta\omega$ as a semitopological semigroup you can also look at dynamical properties, for example there are idempotent ultrafilters (note that, by Ellis's theorem those always exist in ZFC unlike the ultrafilters in my previous comment whose existence is independent)

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti: That should be a proper answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two situations in which we **do** have a *uniquely identifiable* nonprincipal ultrafilter; the first of these is a bit silly (although [not as silly as it may first appear](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008420/consistency-strength-of-the-club-ultrafilter/1008481#comment8403936_1008481)), but the second is quite serious and important.

---

First, let's work in $\mathsf{ZF}$. An **amorphous set** is an infinite set which cannot be partitioned into two infinite subsets. Amorphous sets can carry *some* structure (e.g. it's consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that there is an amorphous set which can be partitioned into *pairs*), but they're quite limited in this regard.

Now consider the **cofinite filter** on an amorphous set $A$. Since $A$ is amorphous this filter is a nonprinicpal ultrafilter - and in fact the *unique* nonprincipal ultrafilter on $A$. Yay!

---

OK, that was silly. What about a $\mathsf{ZFC}$ example?

Well, in general this isn't something we can hope for - despite the fact that there are genuine differences between nonprincipal ultrafilters on the same set (for examples on $\omega$ consider e.g. the topology and algebra of $\beta\omega$ or the Rudin-Keisler ordering). However, we can sometimes get uniqueness in a surprising way: assuming that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ + "There is a measurable cardinal" is consistent in the first place, so is the following:

> $\mathsf{ZFC}$ + "There is a unique measurable cardinal" + "There is exactly one normal ultrafilter on that measurable cardinal."

In fact the situation is even better: if $M\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ and $\kappa$ is measurable in $M$, there is a minimal inner model of $M$ which thinks that $\kappa$ is measurable, and in this inner model there is exactly one normal ultrafilter on $\kappa$. This is treated in Kanamori's book (Theorem $20.10$), and is extremely surprising and cool; it's the start of the development of **inner model theory for large cardinals**.

Comment: Also under V=L we have a uniquely identifiable ultrafilter...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sort of - changing how we enumerate formulas changes what ultrafilter we grab. So I'd say under V=L we do have definable ultrafilters but we don't have any *naturally* definable ultrafilters. This is in contrast with the inner model theoretic result above, which is a genuinely natural definition.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot expect to be able to pinpoint any unique non-principal ultrafilter precisely because such filters cannot be described explicitly. A heuristic argument is that if some property described precisely a non-trivial ultrafilter (say on $\mathbb N$), then presumably that property is prescriptive enough to identify just one ultrafilter. But then you would expect to be able to construct the ultrafilter. Since that cannot be done, it must be the case that the property is just as vague as the axiom of choice is (or whatever choice principle is required on the way to constructing the object).

Comment: As an example the cardinals $\aleph_k$ are unique but cannot be described or fixed in set-theory without some of those extra axioms. If I view the non-principal ultrafilters on $\Bbb N$ as the characters of $\ell^\infty(\Bbb N)/ c_0(\Bbb N)$ then I can describe certain classes of these without being able to constructively prove that any of these classes are non-empty.

Comment: I guess the question is trying to see if ultrafilters can or should be distinguished from one another, so that they are not all the same. The strongest way to do this is to be able to separate one from all the others.

Comment: @s.harp: You need to discern between "pinpoint the actual set" and "provide an explicit definition". While it's true that we can't quite pinpoint which set is $\omega_1$ in the sense that any uncountable regular cardinal is the $\omega_1$ of some universe of set theory with the same ordinals, we can still pinpoint it and define it explicitly. Ultrafilters, however, do not enjoy such a thing. Indeed, it is consistent with ZF that *all* ultrafilters are principal.

Comment: "You cannot expect to be able to pinpoint any unique non-principal ultrafilter precisely because such filters cannot be described explicitly. " This isn't *quite* true, see my answer.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I understand what you mean and I fully agree my answer isn't entirely rigorous as it depends on interpreting what OP precisely meant by asking to pinpoint a unique ultrafilter. E.g., if I proved that ZFC+"there exists a unique ultrafilter such that blah" is consistent, does that count as having pinpointed an ultrafilter? In my answer I was leaning toward a 'no' on such an answer. In your answer, you are learning toward a 'yes'. A bit like saying "in that room, about which we do not know a thing, there is a single elephant". Have we uniquely identified an elephant?

Comment: Sorry what? It can be possible to define non-principal ultrafilters in a unique way. There are ultrafilters that are $\Sigma_1$-definable in $L$.

Comment: @Jonathan perhaps you can elaborate your comment into an answer. As a comment here it adds little.

Answer (score 3):

Non-principal ultrafilters *do* have types and they are studied quite a lot in set theory and model theory.

On the set theoretic side you have ultrafilters that are complete, descendingly complete, you have normal ultrafilter, weakly normal ultrafilters, and you have fine ultrafilters. We have systems of ultrafilters that are coherent in a certain technical sense called "extenders".

When they are sufficiently complete we can study their reflection properties: if $U$ is a $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter on $\kappa$, it can be that there is some $A\in U$ such that for all $\alpha\in A$, $\alpha$ also carries an $\alpha$-complete ultrafilter.

These properties are the defining properties of many large cardinal axioms, and in $\sf ZFC$ we can convert them into elementary embedding that have certain closure properties.

On the other hand, a regular ultrafilter is somehow the strong negation of a complete ultrafilter. These tend to have nice properties in applications to ultrapowers and ultraproducts. For example, if $U$ is a regular ultrafilter on $I$, and $M$ is any set, then $|M^I/U|=|M|^{|I|}$.